# Why does gauge invariance represent interactions in QED?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, interactions

In a recent lecture, my Professor stated that an interaction of a particle can be represented through gauge invariance. I don't quite understand why this should be the case since introducing a gauge field doesn't change the system while the interaction between two particles does (for example, a $W^{\pm}$ can change the lepton flavour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauge forces are mathematically modeled by introducing a field with extra, unphysical degrees of freedom, and then dividing the unphysical part out. Unfortunately, the physical field resulting from that process is given the same name ("gauge") as the unphysical part.

> my Professor stated that an interaction of a particle can be represented through gauge invariance.

Strictly speaking that's wrong, but it's correct if you take it to refer to the whole process of defining fields in this way.

Answer (score 0):

A global gauge invariance does not mean interaction. One needs one more step - requiring a local gauge invariance. And it does not fulfilled automatically. one is obliged to introduce an additional field and its equations. Only then the local gauge invariance holds, but the additional field needs equations of motion too; thus we get gauge invariant interacting theory.